# hash problems with c++ and boost library

Tags: c++, boost, hash, codeblocks, unordered-set

I'm writing a code for graph mining.
Here is the full source code:http://pastebin.com/BpjZPcEi

I'm trying to use std unordered_set but I got problems on this part :

```
bool edgeexist(Graph const& g, int const& fromid, int const& toid, unsigned const& elabel) {
    int bn = 0;

        if (num_edges(g) != 0) {
            edge_pair ep;
            for (ep = edges(g); ep.first != ep.second; ++ep.first) // ep edge number
            {
                vertex_t from = source(*ep.first, g);
                vertex_t to = target(*ep.first, g);
                edge_t edg = edge(from, to, g);

                if ((g[from].id == fromid) && (g[to].id == toid) && (g[edg.first].label == elabel)) {
                    return true;
                }

        }
    }

    return false;
}


std::unordered_set<std::array<int, 3>>  edgesdiff(Graph const& g1,Graph const& g2){

    std::unordered_set<edge_iter> v1,v2,diff;
    std::array<int, 3> t;
    std::unordered_set<std::array<int, 3>> res;


    for(auto x:edges(g1)){

            vertex_t from = source(*x, g1);
            t[0]=g1[from].id;

            vertex_t to = target(*x, g1);
            t[1]=g1[to].id;

            edge_t edg = edge(from, to, g1);
            t[2]=g1[edg.first].label;

        if(!edgeexist(g2,t[0],t[1],t[2])){res.insert(t);}


    }

return res;
}
```

When I run the program on code blocks I got this message:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/hashtable_policy.h|85|error: no match for call to ‘(const hashedge) (const boost::detail::undirected_edge_iter<std::_List_iterator<boost::list_edge<unsigned int, EdgeProperties> >, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, unsigned int>, int>&)’|
```

what's that mean and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

After reading the code, the hash function of an unordered set doesn't take two arguments (let alone a `Graph` *by value* ☹).

You'll need at least something like this (make it readable!!!)

```
struct hashedge {
    hashedge(Graph const &g) : _g(g) {}

    size_t operator()(const edge_iter e) const {
        using namespace boost;
        size_t seed = 42;
        hash_combine(seed, _g[source(*e, _g)]);
        hash_combine(seed, _g[*e].label);
        hash_combine(seed, _g[target(*e, _g)]);
        return seed;
    }

private:
    Graph const &_g;
};
```

This uses divide an conquer to hash the bundled properties. So you define those separately:

```
namespace boost {
template <> struct hash<VertexProperties> {
    size_t operator()(VertexProperties const &v) const {
        using namespace boost;
        auto seed = hash_value(v.id);
        hash_combine(seed, v.label);
        return seed;
    }
};
template <> struct hash<EdgeProperties> {
    size_t operator()(EdgeProperties const &e) const {
        using namespace boost;
        auto seed = hash_value(e.id);
        hash_combine(seed, e.label);
        return seed;
    }
};
}
```

That compiles and works.

Now you have similar issues with the `unordered_set<Graph>`. I'm pretty sure you're looking at this from the wrong end. Can you compare transitive condensations? Can you use filtered graphs?

Here's a partial demo, using `edge_descriptor` instead of `edge_iterator` (because, why iterator?):

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4585aac2296edee9)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>

struct VertexProperties {
    int id;
    int label;
    VertexProperties(unsigned i = 0, unsigned l = 0) : id(i), label(l) {}
};

struct EdgeProperties {
    unsigned id;
    unsigned label;
    EdgeProperties(unsigned i = 0, unsigned l = 0) : id(i), label(l) {}
};

namespace boost {
template <> struct hash<VertexProperties> {
    size_t operator()(VertexProperties const &v) const {
        auto seed = hash_value(v.id);
        hash_combine(seed, v.label);
        return seed;
    }
};
template <> struct hash<EdgeProperties> {
    size_t operator()(EdgeProperties const &e) const {
        auto seed = hash_value(e.id);
        hash_combine(seed, e.label);
        return seed;
    }
};
}

struct GraphProperties {
    unsigned id;
    unsigned label;
    GraphProperties(unsigned i = 0, unsigned l = 0) : id(i), label(l) {}
};

// adjacency_list
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, VertexProperties, EdgeProperties, GraphProperties> Graph;
typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor edge_descriptor;

struct hashedge {
    hashedge(Graph const &g) : _g(g) {}

    size_t operator()(const edge_descriptor e) const {
        using namespace boost;

        size_t seed = 42;
        hash_combine(seed, _g[source(e, _g)]);
        hash_combine(seed, _g[e].label);
        hash_combine(seed, _g[target(e, _g)]);
        return seed;
    }

    private:
    Graph const &_g;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Graph> dataG;
    for (auto& g : dataG) {
        auto es = edges(g);
        std::unordered_set<edge_descriptor, hashedge> edgehash(es.first, es.second, 0ul, hashedge(g));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @sehe for you answer, I tried to put it in my code like this:https://gist.github.com/mohsenuss91/ca09971d6fe4fd3dc49c  But I got `|83|error: ‘edge_descriptor’ does not name a type`

Comment: Really. I'm sure you can figure out how to copy paste. specifically the part where it defines the typedef for `edge_descriptor`. Also note I didn't intend to solve all the problems in that code. But really I'm not sure we're doing you a favour by helping you struggle along

Comment: OK, it's done. I have just some questions about your code please. What do you mean by `size_t seed = 42;` and `0ul` ?

Comment: `size_t seed = 42;` declares a variable of type `size_t` named `seed` and initializes it to some value (42 seems [as good as any](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker's_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29)). `0ul` is the integer literal of type unsigned long.